Serving many MBTiles files using tileserver-gl
I am using tileserver-gl to serve tiles from MBTiles files, which are generated on a daily basis using tippecanoe. Every day a new MBTiles file is generated per a specific id (roughly 200 ids) and these new files needs to be accessible for the running tileserver-gl to serve (alongside the ones generated in the past). The result is that I accumulate a big number of MBTiles files that all of them needs to be accessible for the running tileserver-gl to serve.
In that regard I have 2 questions:

Is there a way of configuring tileserver-gl to scan a directory or path and load all the MBTiles files from that directory as sources, or do I need to add each file as a source to the config.json file in the data field? Because doing that will result in an extremely long config.json file that is just constantly getting bigger and bigger with time.
If there is a way of giving a directory or path and having tileserver-gl load all the MBTiles files in it as sources, are new files added to this directory loaded in the server automatically or does it require a reload of the server for them to be available?

Also, if there isn't a way of simply giving tileserver-gl a directory with all the MBTiles files, how can I serve a growing number of MBTiles with tileserver-gl without blasting the config.json file?
